# Android external storage path structure

Tags: java, android, cordova

The question is a little stupid but sorry.

Does the external storage path has  the same structure   on all android devices ?

Comment: No.  That's why there's a method to return it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although external storage may currently have the same structure on all certified devices (those that have passed the CTS requirements), it's exact nature is an implementation detail. You shouldn't hard-code it. Instead, look at file-related methods in android.content.Context and android.os.Environment.